# Python playback can't chose Bluetooth device in Volume Control

Tags: sound, python, pulseaudio, bluetooth, alsa

Using Radio Tray in Xubuntu 15.10. Outputs fine to headphone jack on the computer. But when I try to change the output to the bluetooth device (Philips Fidelio) in the pulseaudio Volume Control, nothing happens. It continues to use the Analog Stereo output. Is there some python dependencies missing? I can output to the bluetooth headset with other players.

```
$ pactl list short | grep -i bluetooth 
8   module-bluetooth-policy
9   module-bluetooth-discover
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please edit to add terminal results for `pactl list short | grep -i bluetooth`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to switch from speakers to bluetooth headphones is to quit the Radio Tray program then use Sound Settings to set the bluetooth headphones as output device.  Then once I start Radio Tray again it will play through the bluetooth headphones

Comment: I switched over from using Radioplay to Rhythmbox which has a nice panel interface as well...